# React router v4 only renders index page after webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am using react router v4 which is running fine in the developement mode. I am using wepback to make bundle for production and using nginx. Routes and nested routes works fine in development mode, I am also using wepback in development mode. But after making production build and running it on nginx only index route renders.
I don't how to solve this issue. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serve index.html as an answer to any route, as shown here:

https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/.nginx.conf

```
  location / {
    # Set path
    root /var/www/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
```